# Как увеличить скорость динамической загрузки js файлов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

в проекте требуется динамически формировать url на js-скрипты, для этого используется такая функция:

```
function include(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('scipt');
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

но при вызове:

```
...
include(config.host + '/js/jquery.js');
include(config.host + '/js/index.js');
```

jquery не успевает загрузиться и в index.js возникают ошибки вида:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

как ускорить и/или добиться 100% загружаемости вышестоящих скриптов?

Comment: очевидно надо грузить не параллельно, а последовательно

Comment: @Grundy, `последовательно`, значит возникает цепочка зависимостей и функция перестает быть `атомарной` ?

Comment: что значит _функция перестает быть атомарной_?

Comment: @Grundy, у меня встречный вопрос, как реализовать `последовательную` загрузку js-скриптов?

Comment: например начинать следующую загрузку после того как загрузится текущий

Comment: @Grundy, следовательно возникает цепочка зависимостей, и функция перестает быть независимой (атомарной). Почему такой проблемы не возникает при классической загрузке скриптов? `<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>...`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50133/discussion-between-grundy-and-ravend).